# Get-Counter not retrieving valid details

Tags: powershell, taskmanager

I am trying to retrieve I/O details from the task manager using PowerShell. Below is the script that I am trying to use as of now and have had partial success with the same.

```
  $gc = get-counter -ComputerName $($service.ServerName) "\Process($Tservicename)\IO Other Bytes/sec" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
        $OtherBytes=$gc.CounterSamples|Select cookedvalue
```

Here *$serviceName* & *ServerName* is looped through. Below are the issues that I am facing.

1. I am unable to retrieve *IO Other bytes details* for all the service, I am running the script in admin mode so the access shouldn't be an issue.
2. Will the above script give the cumulative result in case there is more than process is executing, for eg for the chrome.exe there would be multiple services running, will it provide an cumulative value. If not how I extract details for each process of the chrome.

[image]

-- Updated Question--

We are using *Get-Counter* cmdlet to retrieve the IO read and write bytes details. This returns 0 for most of the process, is this due to being unable to access system process or due to the access issue.

-- Answer--

After researching a bit realized that value retrieved by the cmdlet is based on that particular instance, which is why we need to sampling of the data by using the *SampleInterval*. However my requirement was sufficed by using the *RawValue*
parameter since I was looking for the value post the server startup as a cumulative value.

1. *List item*

Answer (score 0):

Two important things to understand here:

1. There's not a 1-to-1 relationship between service names and process names
2. Performance counter object instance names don't use process ID's (by default at least)

That means you need to do two levels of instance translation to make sense of the counters:

- Translate Service to Process ID - we can use `Win32_Service` WMI class for this
- Translate Process ID to `Process` counter instances - we can use the `Process(*)\ID Process` counter value for this

```
function Get-ServiceCounter
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string]
    $ServiceName,
    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    [string]
    $ValueName
    [string]
    $Computername = '.'
  )

  $ID = Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter "Name = '${ServiceName}'" -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Select -Expand ProcessID
  if(-not $ID){
    Write-Error "Could not resolve process for service '${ServiceName}'"
    return
  }

  $Instance = Get-Counter -ComputerName $ComputerName "\Process(*)\ID Process" |Where-Object CookedValue -eq $ID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

  if(-not $Instance){
    Write-Error "Could not performance counter instance for Process ID ${ID}"
    return
  }

  Get-Counter ($InstanceName -replace '\\id process',"\${ValueName}") -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction, let me work on it. Meanwhile I have update the question with one more road block.

Comment: I have tweaked the code given by you to fix the errors, however for most of the services it returns zero for the counters such as "read bytes"/ "write bytes". Is there anything specific to be done to capture those